# web.config doubts while working with a legacy app in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, web-config, legacy, optimization

Coding with ASP.NET 2.0 C# on a legacy application. The database is in MySQL

I would like to know whether anything breaks if I delete the following lines from my code

First `<xhtmlConformance mode="Strict"/>`

Then,

```
  <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#" 
              type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" 
              extension=".cs" 
              compilerOptions="/d:DEBUG;trACE"/>
  </compilers>
```

And last,

```
    <browserCaps>
        <case match="^Mozilla/5\.0 \([^)]*\) (Gecko/[-\d]+)(?'VendorProductToken' (?'type'[^/\d]*)([\d]*)/(?'version'(?'major'\d+)(?'minor'\.\d+)(?'letters'\w*)))?">
            browser=Gecko
            <filter>
                <case match="(Gecko/[-\d]+)(?'VendorProductToken' (?'type'[^/\d]*)([\d]*)/(?'version'(?'major'\d+)(?'minor'\.\d+)(?'letters'\w*)))">
                    type=${type}
                </case>
                <case>
                    <!-- plain Mozilla if no VendorProductToken found -->
                    type=Mozilla
                </case>
            </filter>
            frames=true
            tables=true
            cookies=true
            javascript=true
            javaapplets=true
            ecmascriptversion=1.5
            w3cdomversion=1.0
            css1=true
            css2=true
            xml=true
            tagwriter=System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter
            <case match="rv:(?'version'(?'major'\d+)(?'minor'\.\d+)(?'letters'\w*))">
                version=${version}
                majorversion=0${major}
                minorversion=0${minor}
                <case match="^b" with="${letters}">
                    beta=true
                </case>
            </case>
        </case>
        <!-- AppleWebKit Based Browsers (Safari...) //-->
        <case match="AppleWebKit/(?'version'(?'major'\d?)(?'minor'\d{2})(?'letters'\w*)?)">
            browser=AppleWebKit
            version=${version}
            majorversion=0${major}
            minorversion=0.${minor}
            frames=true
            tables=true
            cookies=true
            javascript=true
            javaapplets=true
            ecmascriptversion=1.5
            w3cdomversion=1.0
            css1=true
            css2=true
            xml=true
            tagwriter=System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter
            <case match="AppleWebKit/(?'version'(?'major'\d)(?'minor'\d+)(?'letters'\w*))(.* )?(?'type'[^/\d]*)/.*( |$)">
                type=${type}
            </case>
        </case>
        <!-- Konqueror //-->
        <case match=".+[K|k]onqueror/(?'version'(?'major'\d+)(?'minor'(\.[\d])*)(?'letters'[^;]*));\s+(?'platform'[^;\)]*)(;|\))">
            browser=Konqueror
            version=${version}
            majorversion=0${major}
            minorversion=0${minor}
            platform=${platform}
            type=Konqueror
            frames=true
            tables=true
            cookies=true
            javascript=true
            javaapplets=true
            ecmascriptversion=1.5
            w3cdomversion=1.0
            css1=true
            css2=true
            xml=true
            tagwriter=System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter
        </case>
        <!-- Opera //-->
        <case match="Opera[ /](?'version'(?'major'\d+)(?'minor'\.(?'minorint'\d+))(?'letters'\w*))">
            <filter match="[7-9]" with="${major}">
                tagwriter=System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter
            </filter>
            <filter>
                <case match="7" with="${major}">
                    <filter>
                        <case match="[5-9]" with="${minorint}">
                            ecmascriptversion=1.5
                        </case>
                        <case>
                            ecmascriptversion=1.4
                        </case>
                    </filter>
                </case>
                <case match="[8-9]" with="${major}">
                    ecmascriptversion=1.5
                </case>
            </filter>
        </case>
    </browserCaps>
```

I believe they all are not needed. Are they needed at all at present? What I would really like to know is whether anything breaks if I delete them.

I would also like to know whether the snippet given below is relevant for ASP.NET 2.0

```
  <sessionState mode="InProc" 
              stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" 
              sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes" 
              cookieless="false" 
              timeout="100"/>
```

when my application is using MySQL as database and authentication mode is windows.

Answer (score 2):

The xhtmlConformance setting changes Transitional to Strict. The primary change is that the name attribute is removed from form elements. [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228268%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

The compiler specified is 2.0, so there wont be any actual compiler change. However, compilation defines both the compiler flags debug and trace. These can be used with #if-statements. Both should be removed in production environment, just as you will use . Notice that the compiler settings should be under system.codeDom, not system.web. [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a15ebt6c%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Your browserCaps could (should?) be moved into your App_Browsers folder. You basically defined capabilities of different browsers, and somewhere in your code there are checks if your browser supports specific details, like javascript or frames. This fails bigtime, since browser addons like Noscript will make the detection invalid.

Your sessionState claims to be InProc, which means its handled by the iis process. The connection strings aint used in this mode (you need StateServer or SqlServer for that). Cookieless=false is the default mode, but you've increased the session timeout to 100 (from default 20). [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)